# property CTLineRef not found on object of type UITextView

Tags: iphone

I'm using the below statement for `UITextView` contents to be justified but getting the red warning message property `CTLineRef` not found on object of type `UITextView`.

```
self.textView.CTLineRef justifiedLine = CTLineCreateJustifiedLine(hyphenLine, 1.0, lineWidth);
```

Anyone know what the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

that is because `UITextView` does not have a property called `CTLineRef`. what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to justify the text of uitextview.

Comment: not possible, the text alignment can only be left, center or right aligned. if you need anything more complex you will have to use either a `UIWebView` or Core Text.

Comment: how about kCAAlignmentJustified

Comment: that is for use with a `CATextLayer`, also a possibility if you want basic text layout with justified alignment. it uses core text to do the text rendering.